# I want to split a string from : to \n in Powershell script

Tags: regex, powershell

I am using a config file that contains some information as shown below.

```
User1:xyz@gmail.com
User1_Role:Admin
NAME:sdfdsfu4343-234324-ffsdf-34324d-dsfhdjhfd943
ID:xyz@abc-demo-test-abc-mssql
Password:rewrfsdv34354*fds*vdfg435434
```

I want to split each value from*: to newline* in my Powershell script.
I am using *-split '[: *\n]'* it matches perfectly until there is no '*' in the value. If there is an '*' it will fetch till that. For example, for Password, it matches only *rewrfsdv34354*. Here is my code:

```
$i = 0
foreach ($keyOrValue in $Contents -split '[: *\n]') {
  if ($i++ % 2 -eq 0) { 
    $varName = $keyOrValue 
  } 
  else { 
    Set-Variable $varName $keyOrValue 
  } 
}
```

I need to match all the chars after *: to \n*. Please share your ideas.

Comment: would you mind giving us your script, too?

Comment: $i = 0
foreach ($keyOrValue in $Contents -split '[: *\n]') {
  if ($i++ % 2 -eq 0) { $varName = $keyOrValue }
  else                { Set-Variable $varName $keyOrValue }
}

Comment: Put it in your question please. There is an edit button. Including how you read your values, so we know whats in `$Contents` is.

Comment: Your code in the comment says `-split '[: *\n]'`, the one in your question says `-split '[: \n]`. The former splits on colon, space, asterisk or linefeed, so it's going to split your values on asterisk as it is inside your character set in the square brackets.

Comment: `Set-Variable` can be dangerous as it might overwrite script variables you didn't intend to (especially if the config file is user input). Cleaner: `$config = Get-Content config.cfg -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData -Delimiter ':'` and to access config variables you write e. g. `$config.User1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably best to perform two separate splits here, it makes things easier to work out if the code is going wrong for some reason, although the `$i % 2 -eq 0` part is a neat way to pick up key/value.

I would go for this:

```
# Split the Contents variable by newline first
foreach ($line in $Contents -split '[\n]') {
   # Now split each line by colon
   $keyOrValue = $line -split ':'
   # Then set the variables based on the parts of the colon-split
   Set-Variable $keyOrValue[0] $keyOrValue[1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also convert to a hashmap and go from there, e.g.:

```
$h = @{}
gc config.txt | % { $key, $value = $_ -split ' *: *'; $h[$key] = $value }
```

Or with `ConvertFrom-StringData`:

```
$h = (gc -raw dims.txt) -replace ':','=' | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

Now you have convenient access to keys and values, e.g.:

```
$h
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Password                       rewrfsdv34354*fds*vdfg435434
User1                          xyz@gmail.com
ID                             xyz@abc-demo-test-abc-mssql
NAME                           sdfdsfu4343-234324-ffsdf-34324d-dsfhdjhfd943
User1_Role                     Admin
```

Or only keys:

```
$h.keys
```

Output:

```
Password
User1
ID
NAME
User1_Role
```

Or only values:

```
$h.values
```

Output:

```
rewrfsdv34354*fds*vdfg435434
xyz@gmail.com
xyz@abc-demo-test-abc-mssql
sdfdsfu4343-234324-ffsdf-34324d-dsfhdjhfd943
Admin
```

Or specific values:

```
$h['user1'] + ", " + $h['user1_role']
```

Output:

```
xyz@gmail.com, Admin
```

etc.